# Combining Signin & Signup policy with a resource owner password policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I currently have two different policies for letting the users get the token - one for the interactive flows such as the authorization_code flow and another for resource owner password flow. There is another layer of APIs that we provide above the B2C which proxies the request to B2C for authentication. Based on the grant_type in the request, we are able to redirect to specific custom policy for getting the token. But, redeeming a refresh token also requires that we use same the policy that we use to get the token. The clients won't know which policy to use because they don't directly consume B2C.

Now I am trying to combine Resource Owner Password policy with the interactive policy to achieve this so that we only have one policy. This seems possible for the most part, except that there is no definite way to differentiate or identify the grant types. The claim resolvers such as **{OIDC:GrantType}** or **{OAUTH-KV:grant_type}** don't seem to be provided by B2C.

Is there any claim resolver that I can use to identify the oauth flow within the B2C policy?

Is there any other way to combine the interactive flow with ROPC flow?

Thanks for any input,
Anas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a custom query parameter storing the grant_type from your forwarding API so that you can read it using OAuth2 key-value parameters.

Eg.

- API forwards to the ROPC flow using `{authorization url}&custom_query_param=grant_type`
- You read the `grant_type` value using the {OAUTH-KV:custom_query_param} claim resolver.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Our goal is to not add any additional parameters so that the clients can use the discovery to carry out the login flows without adding flow specific customizations. Since we have an intercepting api proxying the b2c, we will even be able to use two different policies if we go this way. Looks like I have no option but to take this approach :)

Comment: {OIDC:GrantType} or {OAUTH-KV:grant_type} would really help here. Please consider [posting a new idea](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/post/22920db1-ad25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789?g=none&c=a4aa302a-ae25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789) so that the product team knows about your interest.